# How to create a dropdown menu like google's 'More' button?

Tags: css

On google homepage, if you click the more button, a menu opens below just that button, like this:

[image: google screenshot]

How can I do a similar thing with one of the tabs in the navigation bar of my website using css/javascript/jquery?

Edit: To be more specific, I'm wondering how to accomplish the CSS part of this, i.e:

- How to make an up/down arrow graphic show on the tab when the dropdown is toggled. (i.e when toggled, show down arrow, when not, up arrow). (Rather than just putting an `<img>` i'd rather use a background-image to toggle the arrows)
- How to have the new list pop down below the tab and aligned with it.

Comment: You do it by writing the appropriate code used to create what you've envision *(or what someone else has envisioned in this case)*. Do you have a *specific* programming question?

Comment: Yes, he wants to know how to create a dropdown. What's not specific about that?

Comment: @OhMrBigshot: There's absolutely nothing specific about it. It's little more specific than someone asking "how can I create a website". In other words, there's no specific problem to address. It's a very broad description effectively stating... "Here's what I want, how do I do it". A specific problem is... "here's what I'm doing, and here's what I've done, but I'm stuck on this issue".

Comment: @amnotiam Don't know about the person's history, so I won't judge by it. Yes, the question is somewhat generic, but a dropdown is pretty down to business and I don't see a reason not to answer. If I see question that are more generic than this I probably won't answer and say the same, but this case passes imo.

Comment: @OhMrBigshot: Would "how do I write a web server" qualify to you as being specific?

Comment: Stop comparing apples to oranges. I'm not asking how to write a web server or how to make a website. I'm asking specifically how to make a dropdown box similar to what google has, I've even included a screenshot of what I'm seeking. Now please, stop trolling and go somewhere else.

Comment: @ClickUpvote: That is not specific. You're the one trolling this site. I've seen you do it before. You've shown no effort of your own. Sad... just really sad and pathetic.

Comment: If I had trolled or abused the site, I would've been banned. I'm asking a perfectly reasonable question within the guidelines of this site. People like you who come here and derail questions with their off topic clatter rather than just answering the question or downvoting and leaving if they don't like it, are the ones who're trolling.

Comment: And may be the reason I haven't shown any effort is because I don't know where to start. Hence I came here to get help. That's the purpose of this site, yes?

Comment: It is outside the guidelines of the site, and you know it. Unfortunately people rarely take the time to moderate the site, making it easier to abuse with localized questions. And you're lying when you say you don't know where to start. You've answered HTML/CSS/jQuery centric questions. You want someone to do the work for you. I've observed this from you before.

Comment: ...and I never troll this site. I ***help people who care to help themselves*** and respect the guidelines.

Comment: As I've pointed out in my edit, I need help on the CSS part, not the javascript part. I've even pointed out the specific parts of the css that I need help with. If you have a problem with me, email the moderators. Goodbye.

Comment: Ah, so it narrows a *little* closer to a *specific* problem. Maybe you're *starting* to understand. ...sad, just so sad.

Comment: +1  This does not seem to be a negative 1 question to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an example for one way this could be done. Of course, you can experiment with diff methods and stuff, but this is a basic working solution.

A dropdown element to be toggled by clicking a link is pretty good.

```
<div id="topBar">
    <a href="#" id="more">More
        <span id="arrow">
            <span id="arrdown">&#x25BC;</span>
            <span id="arrup">&#x25B2;</span>
        </span>
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <a href="#">One</a>
        <a href="#">Two</a>
        <a href="#">Three</a>
    </div>
</div>​
```

Then you make it toggle with a JS click.

```
$('#more').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $(this).next('.dropdown').toggle();
    return false;
});

$('.dropdown a').click(function() {
    return false;
});
```

css:

```
body { background: #fee; font-family: calibri; }
#topBar { text-align: right; background: black; color: white; padding: 5px; }
#topBar a { color: white; text-decoration: none; padding: 5px 7px; }
#topBar a:hover { background: #ddd; color: black; }
#topBar a.active { background: white; color: black; }
.dropdown { display: none; position: absolute; right: 5px; background: white; color: black; }
.dropdown a { display: block; color: black !important; text-decoration: none; padding: 5px 7px; }
.dropdown a:hover { background: #ccc; }
#arrup { display: none; }
#arrow { font-size: 0.6em; }
```

​

Here's a live example with CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/ZUPBj/

Comment: -1 An off-site link is not an answer. At best, it should be posted as a comment.

Comment: Normally StackOverflow lets you revoke a down-vote when an edit has occurred. There seems to be a bug where it cannot be revoked if the edit happens in the first 5 minutes. Otherwise, I'd remove the DV.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me on the jsfiddle link, clicking more just highlights it but doesn't toggle the menu

Comment: The 'more' link is on the right of the viewport where it also says "Result" in the jsfiddle UI. Try clicking above or below it. For me it works.

Comment: Clicking directly on it seemed to work. If you could add how to toggle an up/down arrow using css (i.e no `<img>` tags) I'll accept. :)

Comment: -1 as this does not trigger the menu when clicking on the "more" text or arrow

Answer (score 2):

There are many different approaches to this, one of the simplest:

Create a hidden div that get's toggled when the menu item is clicked.

```
<div class="menu"></div>
<div class="dropDown"></div> <!-- Hidden by default -->
<script>
    $(".menu").on("click",function(){
        $(".dropDown").toggle();
    });
</script>​​​​
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sAQPB/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm looking more for the css part of how to do this, I've edited the question to clarify

Answer (score 1):

Some googling will find you plenty of tutorials online. I searched for "building drop down menus in html". These links below are some of the better tutorials I found.

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/how-to-build-a-kick-butt-css3-mega-drop-down-menu/

http://www.onextrapixel.com/2011/06/03/how-to-create-a-horizontal-dropdown-menu-with-html-css-and-jquery/

http://youhack.me/2011/09/18/how-to-build-a-drop-down-menu-enhanced-with-css3/

Basically what they're doing is displaying a hidden div when the user hovers over the first level of the menu.